# Using Split() in arithmetic formula

Tags: java, split

I thought a problem for a day but still cannot solve it.
I have a formula input like "11+1+1+2". without space

I want to split the formula according to the operator.
Then I wrote like these:

```
String s = "11+1+1+2";
String splitByOp[] = s.split("[+|-|*|/|%]");
for(int c=0; c < splitByOp.length; c++){
System.out.println(splitByOp[c]);


The output is:
11
1
1
2
```

I want to put the operand(the output) and also the operator(+) into an ArrayList. But how can I keep the operator after spliting them?

I try to have one more Array to split the number.

```
String operator[] = s.split("\\d");
```

But the result is 11 become 1 1. The length of operator[] is 5.

In other words, how can I perform like:

```
The output:
11
+
1
+
1
+
2
```

Comment: *Some people, when confronted with a problem, think 
“I know, I'll use regular expressions.”   Now they have two problems.* -- Jamie Zawinski

Comment: Using "\b" works. I look the meaning of \b in w3schools: Find a match at the beginning/end of a word. Does it means java match automatically?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to split on a regex that is *non consuming*. Specifically, on "word boundary":

```
String[] terms = s.split("\\b");
```

A "word boundary" is the gap between the word char and a non-word char, but digits are classified as word chars. Importantly, the match is non-consuming, so all of the content of the input is preserved in the split terms.

---

Here's some test code:

```
String s = "11+1+1+2";
String[] terms = s.split("\\b");
for (String term : terms)
    System.out.println(term);
```

Output:

```
11
+
1
+
1
+
2
```

Answer (score 0):

You could combine lookahead/lookbehind assertions

```
String[] array = s.split("(?=[+])|(?<=[+])");
```

Answer (score 0):

```
 public static void main(String[] args) {

        String s = "11+1+1+2";
        String[] terms = s.split("(?=[+])|(?<=[+])");
        System.out.println(Arrays.toString(terms));
    }
```

**output**

```
[11, +, 1, +, 1, +, 2]
```